# The TTL result from the windows client is wrong

Tags: ping

I was pinging one of my workstation and the result of my ping, the ttl is be 64 and the workstation is running windows 8.1?
Also i cant access to the PC form DNS name?
I want to know why and how i cant fix it?
thanks...

Comment: Why do you think a TTL of 64 is wrong? That is a common TTL value for pings. Also, questions about application-layer protocols like DNS are off-topic.

Comment: Provide more information:  Can you ping the gateway on both pc's ?.  What is the actual IP's ?.  Do they both work ?

Answer (score 1):

The TTL field in an IPv4 packet is only decremented when the packet is processed by a router. If both computers are on the same subnet, this is not necessary so the TTL will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Some default ttl values:
http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-11&post=Passive-OS-Fingerprinting

Each device can pick it's ttl up to 255 when sending a ip packet, the recommendation is 64, allowing for 64 layer 3 hops before a packet is dropped.

To double check the number of hops, use traceroute.

Comment: i was traceroute the system and there is no hope in the path to the system. the OS system is windows and generally the TTL has to be 128 but in this PC is 64 and i can't access to the PC by DNS name.
I want to know how i can fix this problem.

Comment: ali-m, if you cant ping a local pc, your problem is not the ttl.